# Fragment lags while enter animation

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-jetpack

Fragment lags while enter animation. I am using navigation jetpack and while navigating in between the fragments, the one which is included with recycler view shows some lag. Sometime the animation is just skipped and sometime it shows lagging.

The recycler view gets updated with the api calls in on view created method.

Comment: Sounds like you have the RecyclerView in a NestedScrollView or have nested scrolling disabled

Comment: whats in your layout file? we cant tell solution without finding the cause

Comment: Even if you do everything right, If your list items are complex, layout can be time-consuming enough to make the fragment transaction animation laggy. Consider adding a 300ms delay before flow collection / live data observation.